# Copy a table from Word to Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Pls help! I want to copy a specific table from a word file with 8 tables. My code is running but I am using an index to retrieve the table. Instead, I want to copy the table using keywords from the table. Let's say how can I copy a table from Word filtering specific information from that table only. For example in my code, I am copying table number 6 but instead how can I copy that same table from word by filtering Nbr1 rows only.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
enter code here


 Option Explicit
    
    
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    copyTableDataFromWord
End Sub

Public Sub copyTableDataFromWord()
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Create a "FileDialog" object as a File Picker dialog box.
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    Dim sfileName As String
    
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Title = "Select a Word File"
        .Filters.Add "All Word Documents", "*.doc?", 1
    
        If .Show = True Then
            sfileName = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))      ' Get the file.
        End If
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    If Trim(sfileName) <> "" Then
        Dim objWord As Object       ' Create a Word object.
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWord.Visible = False      ' Do not show the file.
        
        ' Create a Document object and open the Word file.
        Dim objDoc
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(fd.InitialFileName & sfileName)
            
        Dim iTable    ' The table that you want to extract data.
        iTable = 6 ' Set value as 2 or 3 for second or third table (if any).

        ' Note: If you have multiple tables in your word file,
        '  use "objDoc.tables.Count" to get the total tables in the file
        '  and loop through each table.
        
        If objDoc.tables(iTable).Columns.Count > 0 Then     ' Check if it’s a table.
        
            Dim iTotalCols As Integer   ' Get total columns in the table.
            iTotalCols = objDoc.tables(iTable).Columns.Count
            
            Dim iTotalRows As Integer   ' Get total rows in the table.
            iTotalRows = objDoc.tables(iTable).Rows.Count
            
            Dim iRows, iCols As Integer
            Dim txt As Variant
            
            ' Get the table headers first.
            For iCols = 1 To objDoc.tables(iTable).Columns.Count
                txt = objDoc.tables(iTable).cell(1, iCols).Range.Text
                With Sheet1
                    .Cells(1, iCols) = Replace(txt, " ", "")          ' Write the headers in sheet1.
                    .Cells(1, iCols).Font.Bold = True
                End With
            Next iCols
    
            ' Now extract the table data.
            For iRows = 2 To iTotalRows
                For iCols = 1 To iTotalCols
                    txt = objDoc.tables(iTable).cell(iRows, iCols).Range.Text
                    Sheet1.Cells(iRows, iCols) = Replace(txt, " ", "")   ' Show data in sheet1.
                Next iCols
            Next iRows
        End If
        
        ' Add borders to the table.
        Sheet1.UsedRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Clean up.
    objWord.Close
    objDoc.Quit
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
   End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried adding to the code to implement your idea? Where did you run into trouble with it? Please include that in your question.

Comment: "specific information" is not a very specific description of exactly what you want to do.  You already know how to read the cell contents in the Word tables, so what specific problem are you having with altering this code?

Comment: In my word file, I have several tables. My question is how can I copy a table from word by the information in it instead of going by table index which is not very accurate?

Comment: You can test the text in the table and looks for the rows of interest.  Did you try that?

Comment: Do you have a property by which you can recognize the correct table (title, ID, description)?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, do you have a sample code maybe? Tim Williams

Comment: Yes, I have a description before the table. A brief description on top of the table that says Sales of the month. I intend to copy the table after that description. "Shrotter"

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of what I was suggesting:

```vb
Public Sub copyTableDataFromWord()
    
    Dim doc As Object, tbl As Object, rw As Object, txt, id
    Dim cDest As Range, app As Object
    
    Set doc = GetWordDoc()
    If doc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    id = "Nbr1"
    Set cDest = ActiveSheet.Range("A2") 'start copying rows to here
    For Each tbl In doc.tables
        For Each rw In tbl.Rows
            If WordCellText(rw.Cells(1)) = id Then
                RowToRange rw, cDest
                Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1) 'next destination row
            End If
        Next rw
    Next tbl
    Set app = doc.Application
    doc.Close False
    app.Quit 'close word
End Sub
   
'transfer a word table row to Excel range
Sub RowToRange(rw As Object, rng As Range)
    Dim cell As Object, i As Long, txt
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In rw.Cells
        rng.Offset(0, i).Value = WordCellText(cell)
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub

'Return the content of a word table cell, minus the end-of-cell marker
Function WordCellText(cell As Object)
    With cell.Range
        WordCellText = Left(.Text, Len(.Text) - 2) 
    End With
End Function

'get a user-selected Word document
Function GetWordDoc() As Object
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim sfileName As String, objWord As Object, objDoc As Object
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Title = "Select a Word File"
        .Filters.Add "All Word Documents", "*.doc?", 1
        If .Show = True Then
            sfileName = .SelectedItems(1)      ' Get the file.
            Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            objWord.Visible = True     ' Do not show the file.
            Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(sfileName)
            Set GetWordDoc = objDoc
        End If
    End With
End Function
```